# How to call one specific method whenever its record was accessed by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two field `secret_question` and `secret_answer` into the `Student` model, i store these two fields in encrypted form. I have `encrypt` method which runs `after_save` and make those field encrypted. I have `decrypt` method too which `decrypt` these two field and load data into the **memory**.  The below example will help you to understand

```
def decrypt
  # notice  that i dont save the decrypted data, it is just loaded into the memory 
  self.secret_question = decrypt_data(secret_question)
  self.secret_answer = decrypt_data(secret_answer)
  self
end
```

The problem with this approach is i have to call `decrypt` method every time when i have to show/use/compute these required field.

I am looking for some way so that whenever i call `Student` model, it will have these two fields (`secret_question` and `secret_answer`) decrypted.

So far, i have done in this in `student`

```
 def self.find(*args)
    s = super(*args)
    s.decrypt
    s
 end
```

but these may not work with `associations` i.e `school_class.students` wont have `decrypt` method called by default. Is there any way to make `decrypt` method called whenever `student` model is accessed ?

PS: above is the contrived example and encrypting the data is our business requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[after_initialize](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find) should be helpful for you.

Note that after_initialize will be triggered even for new objects as well, so you may want to put a guard condition.

Ex:

```
after_initialize :decrypt, if: :persisted?
```